# Launch web driver chrome browser through web api call

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-web-api, selenium-webdriver

I want to launch the Chrome browser using Web Api call. I'm able to launch it using the below code while running through Visual Studio 
URL:  http://localhost:64001/api/values

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    //private TechTalk.SpecFlow.ITestRunner testRunner;

    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        IWebDriver driver;
        var webDriversPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/WebDrivers");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(webDriversPath);

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

But, the issue is while publish into IIS try to access the URL: http://localhost/MyApp/Api/Values

I'm getting the below exception.

```
<Error>
<Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
<ExceptionMessage>
The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
</ExceptionMessage>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException</ExceptionType>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at    OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
</StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Can you please help me to fix this.

Comment: string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
                        
 
string reportPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(path, @"..\") + @"\bin\WebDrivers");

Comment: Hi Hina Khuman, Thanks for your response. I tried to implement the same code but still i couldnt lanuch chrome while entering the url: http://localhost/MyApp/Api/Values  Let me know any other ideas to fix this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Spent some time working on this for myself and this route worked for me. Some issues arise for running selenium via IIS as the user my have permission issues or problems running GUI sessions without being associated to a GUI itself so it will "run" but become stuck. What worked for me will require you to alter your web API implementation to utilize remote web driver. Shouldn't be a big deal...worse case you might have to change a bunch of driver.FindElementsById to driver.FindElements(By.Id(""));

So what worked for me is

1. Download selenium stand alone server: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
2. You have the option of running selenium in grid mode but for this purpose, you can just run selenium standalone to handle chrome only. To do so run the following command.

Important note here that tripped me up some, run this from command prompt instead of powershell. Not sure why but powershell didn't cooperate well with the -D command line argument and kept giving me classpath errors.

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/utilities/selenium/chromedriver.exe -jar c:\utilities\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -port 5556 -browser "browserName=chrome, version=ANY, maxInstances=10, platform=WINDOWS"

3. Alter your web API code to implement RemoteWebDriver, you should have this included in your project already...that is assuming you got your DLL's for selenium from nuget. To do this your web api Action in the Values controller code should look something like this

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var opts = new ChromeOptions();

        var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:5556/wd/hub"), opts);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");

        return Ok(new { msg = "All done" });
    }
```

Notice here where 5556 port on the webdriver URL is the same port specified in the command line argument from #3. If you change that port, you'll need to change it here as well. If you don't provide the port argument, I believe the default would be 4444.

4. Once you've altered your web api code to implement remote web driver you'll need to make sure the selenium stand alone implementation is always running wherever your web API app will exist, from there you should be able to launch

If you are interested in running selenium in grid mode, have a look at this link:

https://community.perfectomobile.com/posts/1101012-selenium-grid-server-configuration-hub-node-setup-for-chrome-firefox-safari-ie

This worked for me and a lot of the issues/answers were more java specific so hopefully this helps .net implementations.

Answer (score -1):

the execution of the following command did you perform in

```
windows?java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/utilities/selenium/chromedriver.exe -jar c:utilitiesseleniumselenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -port 5556 -browser "browserName=chrome, version=ANY, maxInstances=10, platform=WINDOWS" . I get a mistake :  "java" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
Executable program or batch file.
```