# docker: c# how to run selenium via webapi

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

I am running a test PoC web api. I am running Selenium test inside a web api endpoint. Everything works fine locally, but when I am running it on Docker Image. I get the error:

```
System.Exception:    at Interop.Sys.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setUser, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, Int32& lpChildPid, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean shouldThrow)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService.Start()
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
```

I am using a simple chromedriver locally to run it, but I am not sure of the difference of my local code vs when I create an image in docker. Thanks for any help. I have been reading up a lot on both docker and selinum but have yet to find anything.

Code that fails:

```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.AddArgument("headless");
  options.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
  ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "chromedriver");
  _driver = new ChromeDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

References I have been using:

- [Selenium in Docker with DotNetCore, Chrome in Linux and Headless
  Mode](https://medium.com/devpassis/selenium-in-docker-with-dotnetcore-chrome-in-linux-and-headless-mode-993ba422ebcf)
- [Launch web driver chrome browser through web api call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504884/launch-web-driver-chrome-browser-through-web-api-call)
- [Docker Selenium - GitHub
  repository](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer. I ended up using a `RemoteWebDriver` from a docker image [HERE](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium). Everything is working fine now after following the instructions.